# Custom Instruction in RISCV

Tags: riscv

I am following the gem5 to add the custom instruction. My question is how to the interpret operands mentioned in "const struct riscv_opcode riscv_opcodes[]" in riscv-opc.h. 
For an example :
`{"mod",       "I",   "d,s,t",  MATCH_MOD, MASK_MOD, match_opcode, 0 }`
.how "d,s,t" are interpret here?
Can anyone explain the this whole statement

refLink :https://nitish2112.github.io/post/adding-instruction-riscv/

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment at the top of the array describing the instructions :
`/* name,      isa,   operands, match, mask, match_func, pinfo.  */`

The line says that 
`{"mod",       "I",   "d,s,t",`

`mod` belongs to the Integer ISA and that it is a triadic instruction, meaning that it takes 3 registers whose symbolic names are d,s,t.
d being the destination register, s and t being source registers.

Comment: Thanks. but there are other operands as well. Do you know any documentation of this which states the mechanism of using operands

Comment: This is described in the url you have quoted - MASK_MOD is the mask used to isolate the opcode from the other part of the instruction, MATCH_MOD is compared against the instruction that have been masked. Upon match, it calls the match_function. So it mimics a decoder logic. However, the last parameter is less obvious to me - may be just a way to have the same instruction used in different ISA (I & C for instance).

Comment: Thanks.. I have implemented the custom instruction by using the operands : "d,s,t,j". In which d for rd , s for rs1, t for rs2 and j for 12 bit immediate value.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost 4 years old, but since I spent a lot of time figuring out similar things, I would like to post my knowledge in case anyone needs it.

"mod" is the instruction label, "I" is the type of the instruction and in this case, it is an integer instruction. It takes three registers, the destination "d" register and the source registers "s" and "t".

The MASK_MOD and MATCH_MOD are used for the instruction matching in the assembler. The instruction matching is done by the function match_opcode that you are passing in the next parameter. This function does the instruction matching is done as follows:

```
((insn ^ MATCH_MOD) & MASK_MOD) == 0
```

This means that the instruction (32 bits in length) is XOR'ed with the MATCH_MOD and then the result is AND'ed with the MASK_MOD. The result must always be zero to match the "mod" instruction that you are adding. This means you have to define the instruction opcode, FUNCT7, and FUNCT3 accordingly in the `riscv-opcodes/opcodes` file included in RISCV-GNU-Toolchain. You should also define the MASK_MOD and MATCH_MOD in `riscv-isa-sim/riscv/encoding.h`.